# How to change deployment target in Cordova

Tags: cordova, cocoapods, visual-studio-app-center

I have a plugin that requires a higher deployment target than 8.0. I can change my pod file but Cordova always changes it back. Is there a way to set that? I tried:

```
<preference name="deployment-target" value="10.0" />
```

in config.xml.

My problem is that I always get this on install:
[image]

Which results in:
[image]

Comment: For cocoa pods issues I recently used this plugin 
https://github.com/blakgeek/cordova-plugin-cocoapods-support 
I hope it could be good in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So even though

```
cordova plugin list
```

showed the plugins added, they actually were not in the folder. The only one there was cordova-plugin-appcenter-shared so I deleted it from both plugin folders and re ran

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-appcenter-analytics
```

and everything installed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are receiving the `CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "AppCenter"` ... `Specs satisfying the 'AppCenter (~> 1.13.2) dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target` you are likely targeting iOS less than 9 and your Podfile is being generated with an AppCenter version specified.

I believe [AppCenter 0.3.0](https://github.com/Microsoft/AppCenter-SDK-Cordova/releases/tag/0.3.0) is responsible for changing the iOS Podfile from `pod 'AppCenter'` to `pod 'AppCenter ~> 1.13.2'` (or 1.12.0 in your case)

You can try to force the Podfile to target iOS 9 or higher by adding Cordova config.xml 'deployment-target' preference with value of "9.0" however that will not work on cordova-ios 4.5.5+. Otherwise you'd have to manually change the Podfile or the target in Xcode (neither are recommended). Alternatively, you can downgrade the AppCenter SDK/plugins to 0.2.2 for the short term so that the Podfile doesn't specify the AppCenter version.

Answer (score 0):

code in yours config.xml

```
<preference name="deployment-target" value="10.0" />
```

will work only after command:

```
cordova platform add ios
```